# I've been having some trouble with a precalculus question. It's in the body.

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been on this problem for a while now, but haven't been able to get through part b. I was able to get the first part, though.

Consider a convex quadrilateral with vertices at $a, b, c$ and $d$ and on each side draw a square lying outside the given quadrilateral, as in the picture below. Let $p, q, r$ and $s$ be the centers of those squares:

[image]

a) Find expressions for $p, q, r$ and $s$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and $d$.

b) Prove that the line segment between $p$ and $r$ is perpendicular and equal in length to the line segment between $q$ and $s$.

For part a, I had, if we were trying to find p for instance:
$$p = a + \frac{\sqrt2}2 e^{-\pi i/4}  (b-a)$$

I just don't know what to do with b from here.

Just to note, I'm a precalculus student

Comment: Use that $$\frac{\sqrt2}2e^{\pi i/4}=\frac 12-i\frac12$$ you get $$p=\frac12((1+i)a+(1-i)b)$$

Comment: You could note that $(a-p) = i(b-p)$, so $p = \frac{a-bi}{1-i}$, which can be simplified to $\frac12(a-b) - \frac i2(a+b)$. My first equality comes from the fact that you can obtain segment $pa$ by rotating segment $pb$ through a right angle counterclockwise about $p$.

Answer (score 1):

$ p = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{a-b}{2} i$ , $q = \frac{b+c}{2} +\frac{b-c}{2}i $ , $ r = \frac{c+d}{2} + \frac{c-d}{2}i $ , $s = \frac{d+a}{2} + \frac{d-a}{2}i$

$ 2(r-p) = (c-a)(1+i)+(d-b)(1-i)$ , $ 2(s-q) = (d-b)(1+i) + (a-c)(1-i)$

$ \therefore  2(s-q) = 2(r-p)  \cdot i $

Use that $ i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$